# How to change the background image of a QMainWindow central widget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, background-image, pyqt5

I'm trying to change the background image of the `QMainWindow` central widget. The `QMainWindow`'s background is fairly easy to change but I can't get the same result with it's central widget. What I tried is the code

```
self.mdi = QMdiArea()
self.options_window = Options()
self.central_widget = QStackedWidget()
self.mdi.setStyleSheet("{background-image: url(ninja.png);}")
self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
self.central_widget.addWidget(self.mdi)
self.central_widget.addWidget(self.options_window)
self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(self.mdi)
```

I also tried with this one

```
self.mdi = QMdiArea()
self.options_window = Options()
self.central_widget = QStackedWidget()
self.central_widget.setStyleSheet("{background-image: url(ninja.png);}")
self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
self.central_widget.addWidget(self.mdi)
self.central_widget.addWidget(self.options_window)
self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(self.mdi)
```

Could anyone give me a light in this problem?

Comment: try with my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the background image of a QWidget you should override the paintEvent method, in your case yours in a QStackedWidget, we create a class that inherits from this:

```
class StackedWidget(QStackedWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QStackedWidget.__init__(self, parent=parent)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), QPixmap("ninja.png"))
        QStackedWidget.paintEvent(self, event)
```

And then you change:

```
self.central_widget = QStackedWidget()
```

to:

```
self.central_widget = StackedWidget()
```

Example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class StackedWidget(QStackedWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QStackedWidget.__init__(self, parent=parent)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), QPixmap("image.png"))
        QStackedWidget.paintEvent(self, event)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.setCentralWidget(StackedWidget())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Screenshot:

[image]

The case of QStackedWidget is a special case since this is not shown, this serves to show other widgets, to those widgets you must change the background image.

From your code, the first widget they attach is a `QMdiArea`, this is also a special case since it has a viewport and this should be changed.

```
class MdiArea(QMdiArea):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMdiArea.__init__(self, parent=parent)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        QMdiArea.paintEvent(self, event)
        painter = QPainter(self.viewport())
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), QPixmap("image.png"))
```

In your code change:

```
self.mdi = QMdiArea()
```

to:

```
self.mdi = MdiArea()
```

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: the `QPainter(self)` is complaining with the `self` argument, then I don't know if it didn't work because of this or anything else. Warning: Expected QPaintDevice, got StackedWidget instead

Comment: I think you implemented it wrong, you could share your code through github, drive or similar to show you how to do it please

Comment: @MatheusFernando Look at the example I've placed.

Comment: here's the drive link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B17RZyeHhRfZZTNiZ1N1cFhfdG8

Comment: Please the code you are missing certain classes or functions, you could share that too. One question, the QStackedWidget is never displayed, that widget is used to display other widgets, maybe you want QMainWindow to have that background?

Comment: I uploaded the whole code, here's a picture of where I want to change: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B17RZyeHhRfZM0VoNEx1cjNWNFE

Comment: It's working perfectly now, thank you very much @eyllanesc